# How to obtain zuora solution architect certification?

Tags: zuora, zuora-soap

Hi all This might be an off-topic question but i didnt find any solution so asking here..

How can i obtain zuora solution architect certification?

what will be the certification procedure??

what does one need to study in zuora to take up the certification test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To obtain a zuora certification you MUST be a partner or Employee of zuora.
2. You must login using your work email
3. You must enroll to the courses
4. At last u have to take up Solution Architect exam.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://community.zuora.com/t5/Zuora-Announcements/Big-Announcements-from-Zuora-University/ba-p/11268) from the Zuora Community re: Zuora University's upcoming training and tests to become a certified Zuora Administrator.  It's set to be released by the end of our fiscal year (early 2017-ish).

Hope that helps